# How to add multiple graphs next to each other in excel?

Tags: excel, graph

I have 3 data sheets for 3 separate years, each sheet has two columns (Date and data), is there a way to add all three years in a single graph next to each other? I tried to add them all in one sheet but each one is one-million rows and exceeds excel's sheet limit.

Comment: what is "each one"? What does your data look like? Too many data points and certain kinds of graph become inappropriate. What kind of graph were you considering? Solution will depend  on the answer to some of these questions.

Comment: If you manage to create a graph of a million data points, you'll probably never be able to do anything in that sheet ever again! Excel will redraw the graph if you so much as sneeze. You should do some data reduction - there's no point plotting more than 10,000 points on a graph.

Comment: each one is each sheet, i have 3 sheets of 3 different eyars, each sheet is 1 million rows of data. I made three graphs for each sheet i need to combine the three graphs next to each other, thats it.

Comment: How many actual rows of data do you have in each sheet? As per my comment and Troy's any chart with as many data points as you seem to be suggesting would be an exercise in futility.

Comment: the first two sheets have 1,022,000 rows the last one has 876,000 rows

Comment: And how will you interpret this if you can create one chart from it? And what kind of chart would it be? These are more important questions than can i do it. Should i do it comes first. End of sermon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the individual graphs on the individual sheets.

Then on the 2nd and 3rd sheets, right click on the graph and choose "Move Chart..."

Select sheet1. Now you can arrange them as you like.

Comment: Method 1 has worked, but it added the data together, I want them to be next to each other i.e. extending the x-axis to enter the new year from sheet2

Comment: I think it depends what kind of chart you're using. What type did you hope to use? A scatter chart should work.

Comment: i used line, let me try scatter

Comment: I did it ok using method 2. Method 1 doesn't work, I'll remove that from my answer

Comment: Thank for the help, but I tried doing this and yet it still adds it inside the first graph not next to it, when i click select data, i can see the new xaxis labels on the right side but they are not appearing on the graph

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159770/discussion-between-troy-wray-and-abdane).